# Python - Converting large CSV file to JSON

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, csv

I have a 4.5GB CSV file that I am trying to convert to JSON using Python 2.7. I have it working fine with a smaller 500mb file however I run out of memory on the bigger one. How do I turn what I have coded into something that reads a CSV file in chunks and write (append in chunks) to a JSON file?

```
f = open('table-52007-changeset.csv', 'rb' )
reader = csv.DictReader(f) 

out = json.dumps( [ row for row in reader ] )  
json_response = json.loads(out)

jsonoutput = 'masterlist2.0.json'
with open(jsonoutput, 'a') as f:
    for x in json_response: 
        json.dump(x,f)
        f.write('\n')
```

Comment: why the *dump, load, dump* dance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently reading the entire structure into memory with the line:

```
out = json.dumps( [ row for row in reader ] )
```

Instead just go straight to json one row at a time like:

```
import json
import csv

with open('table-52007-changeset.csv', 'r') as input_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(input_file)

    jsonoutput = 'masterlist2.0.json'
    with open(jsonoutput, 'a') as output_file:
        for row in reader:
            json.dump(row, output_file)
            f.write('\n')
```